# SourceMap with Sass filter in assetic?

Tags: symfony, sass, assetic

As far as I see in https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/blob/master/src/Assetic/Filter/Sass/SassFilter.php, there is some support for SourceMap when compiling scss files.

However, I cannot seem to find any examples of real-life usage. Is there a configuration option(s) or parameters for the sass filter that result in being able to generate sourcemaps ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing this, symfony natively comes with version 1.2 of assetic. The `sourceMaps` feature isn't on the 1.2 version. It's only on master.